# WordPress database error while access the subcategory

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am getting issue while access the subcategory :

URL: https://www.webinfosys.net/projects/musclerox/colour-pigments/inorganic-pigments/

> WordPress database error: [You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near ') ORDER BY t.name ASC' at line 1]
>       SELECT t.*, tt.* FROM wp_terms AS t INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS tt ON t.term_id = tt.term_id WHERE tt.taxonomy IN ('category') AND
>   t.term_id NOT IN() ORDER BY t.name ASC

and

> WordPress database error: [You have an error in your SQL syntax; check
>   the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near ') ORDER BY wp_termmeta.meta_value+0 ASC, t.name
>   ASC' at line 3] SELECT DISTINCT t.*, tt.* FROM wp_terms AS t LEFT JOIN
>   wp_termmeta ON ( t.term_id = wp_termmeta.term_id AND
>   wp_termmeta.meta_key='order') INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS tt ON
>   t.term_id = tt.term_id WHERE tt.taxonomy IN ('product_cat') AND
>   t.term_id IN ( 39,89,88,169 ) AND tt.count > 0 AND ( (
>   wp_termmeta.meta_key = 'order' OR wp_termmeta.meta_key IS NULL ) ) AND
>   t.term_id NOT IN() ORDER BY wp_termmeta.meta_value+0 ASC, t.name ASC

I have updated my mysql version but didn't get work.

> WordPress database error: [You have an error in your SQL syntax; check
>   the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near ') ORDER BY wp_termmeta.meta_value+0 ASC, t.name
>   ASC' at line 3] SELECT DISTINCT t.*, tt.* FROM wp_terms AS t LEFT JOIN
>   wp_termmeta ON ( t.term_id = wp_termmeta.term_id AND
>   wp_termmeta.meta_key='order') INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS tt ON
>   t.term_id = tt.term_id WHERE tt.taxonomy IN ('product_cat') AND
>   t.term_id IN ( 39,89,88,169 ) AND tt.count > 0 AND ( (
>   wp_termmeta.meta_key = 'order' OR wp_termmeta.meta_key IS NULL ) ) AND
>   t.term_id NOT IN() ORDER BY wp_termmeta.meta_value+0 ASC, t.name ASC

Comment: Why NOT IN() is empty ?? And what you trying to achieve by this complex query as wp already have lots of predefined functions to retrieve data of custom taxonomy, I suggest to use meta query instead of this SQL complex query.

Comment: You absolutely need to share more details. Is there any custom code involved?

Comment: No i don't add any custom code recently. Can you please ask what you have need more details i will share the same.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you are using SQL to retrieve categories or WordPress function. Bur your correct queries will be:

```
SELECT t.*, tt.* FROM wp_terms AS t INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS tt ON t.term_id = tt.term_id WHERE tt.taxonomy IN ('category') ORDER BY t.name ASC
```

and

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.*, tt.* FROM wp_terms AS t LEFT JOIN wp_termmeta ON ( t.term_id = wp_termmeta.term_id AND wp_termmeta.meta_key = 'order' ) INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS tt ON t.term_id = tt.term_id WHERE tt.taxonomy IN ('product_cat') AND t.term_id IN (39, 89, 88, 169) AND tt.count > 0 AND ( wp_termmeta.meta_key = 'order' OR wp_termmeta.meta_key IS NULL ) ORDER BY wp_termmeta.meta_value + 0 ASC, t.name ASC
```

If you are using Wordpress functions to get the categories, please post your code here so that I can check and fix.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your support I am not using any custom query this website running well suddenly we getting that issue and i am new to WordPress i have no idea where is code defined.

Comment: Then I suggest checking with your theme author. Is there a new version of the theme available? Try updating your theme.

Comment: I have updated the theme and wordpress version. but getting same issue.

Comment: Then try switching to the parent theme or a default theme. Also, disable all the plugins.

Comment: I have trying the same that you suggested but didn't work. I more thing when i am adding a new category from product=>category then item added but not showing in admin category list.

Comment: When i have replace wp_option & wp_post table with old database backup then its working fine. i don't know whats wrong with current database?

Comment: Can u check if Current DB and old DB have same structure like- primary key, number of columns. I have worked on some projects where DB structure was not proper and there were repeated primary keys in tables. Also, try to match the configuration of themes and plugin as it was on the old DB